# Ref cursor with Execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor, execute-immediate

I want to get the results in ref_cursor, but I am not able to do that.

Please suggest me how to get the results in ref_cursor using Execute immediate

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC_QT ( p_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                           p_result_set OUT sys_refcursor ) IS

  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

   v_sql := '';
   v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE 1=1 ';

   IF p_name is not null THEN
     v_sql := v_sql || ' AND login_id = :v_name';
   ELSE
     v_sql := v_sql || ' AND ((1=1) or :v_name is null)';
   END IF;

   Dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql

   --OPEN p_result_set for v_sql
   --INTO p_result_set using p_name;  

END;
```

Comment: Completely unrelated but a better way of writing the query (with no execute immediate) is: 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE login_ID = nvl(:v_name, login_id)'

Comment: @Thomas Jones-Low: that ain't gonna work if you have an index on that column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just:

```
OPEN p_result_set for v_sql using p_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create a type to keep the data you select is going to return,for example.
   Imagine this is yours users table `user(id number, name varchar2)`, your type should look like:

   ```
   create type users_type as object (id number, name varchar2);
   ```
2. Create a type table to keep object to created above.

   ```
   create type users_table_object as table of users_type;
   ```
3. create the procedure:

   ```
   create the procedure test(
   cv_1  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
   ....
   )
   as
   users_table_object;
   v_query VARCHAR2(2000);  

   begin
   v_query := N'select users_type(id, name) from users ';

   execute immediate
   bulk collect into users_table_object;

   open cv_1 for table(users_table_object)
   ```

Comment: It does not compile: `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following: ...` happens on last string